# How can we extract London weather in 2000 via Darksky API?

Tags: r, weather, darksky

```
#install.packages("darksky")
library(darksky)
library(tidyverse)

# current verison
packageVersion("darksky")

Sys.setenv("DARKSKY_API_KEY" = # Secret API Key
             )
Sys.getenv("DARKSKY_API_KEY")

#This coordinates works 
now <- get_current_forecast(43.2672, -70.8617)
print(now)
```

## Trying to extract temperature info for London ...

```
seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2001-01-01"), "day") %>% 
  map(~get_forecast_for(51.5074, 0.1278, .x)) %>% 
  map_df("daily") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=time, y=temperature)) +
  geom_line()´
```

## But got access forbidden HTTP 403 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP 403 error states, that you have not access to the called website. So this means your key is wrong. First of you need to create an account on [darksky](https://darksky.net/dev). Please be aware: you just get 1000 api calls per day for free (check the [faq](https://darksky.net/dev/docs/faq)), if you want to call the whole year you already got 365 api calls, since you are doing one call per day. So try with smaller dates first.

You can enter the API Key by using `darksky_api_key()` which gives you the chance to enter your key in the console. Otherwise you can create an .Renviron file and add the key there (for this check the [documentary](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/darksky/darksky.pdf) of the darksky package).

So after adding the key in the console, here a code working example from [github](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/darksky)  (which i guess, you also used). Adapt the date and the plot for your case, i used just one month of data because of the call limit.

```
library(darksky)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

# current verison


darksky_api_key()

#This coordinates works 
now <- get_current_forecast(43.2672, -70.8617)
print(now)

df <- seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2000-02-02"), "day") %>% 
  map(~get_forecast_for(51.5074, 0.1278, .x)) 

df %>%
  map_df("hourly") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=time, y=temperature)) +
  geom_line()
```

Output:
[image: Output plot]

Comment: Thanks, yes my API calls were over yesterday. I was wondering using this API
https://github.com/hrbrmstr/darksky, If we can get to know about snow details such as snow start date in a particular region and amount (precipAmount). Because in their website, they mentioned snowFall data is available but not sure to extract such info.

Comment: @Abhi sadly i'm not aware how to extract snowfall data. I can't find a way to do this with the package. Maybe you should contact the owner on Github about this issue